# Bootstrap 4 tooltip use custom attribute other than title to provide the text for the tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an application where I am using Bootstrap 4 with tooltips. I want to toggle the tooltips one by one and show them only on click. I am able to do this using:

```
 <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" 
 data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Write name here.">
```

I am showing the tooltip individually using the following javascript which gets triggered on button click:

```
 $('#name').tooltip("show");
```

and I hide/dispose of it using the following script:

```
 $('#name').tooltip("dispose");
```

The reason I use dispose is because I do not want the tooltip to be visible unless the button is pressed.

The issue is that on mouseover of the input field, the browser (in my case Firefox Developer Edition) shows the tooltip with its own style because the tooltip text is in the `title` attribute.

Is there a way in bootstrap to instead hold the text to be shown in another `data-tooltiptitle` attribute for e.g.:

```
<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" 
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-tooltiptitle="Write name here.">
```

And then maybe tell the tooltip to use the `data-tooltiptitle` attribute for the text using some jQuery.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `title` option and set it as a function. On hover, this function will get called with the instance of the hovered element. Using `getAttribute`, you can then fetch the custom attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    title: function() {
      return 'No Hooray!!';
    }
  });
  $('#link').tooltip({
    title: function() {
      return this.getAttribute('custom-title');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" custom-title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>

<input type="text" id="link" custom-title="Hooray!">
```

Comment: Thanks for a solution, but this does not work specifically for my question. The code works for `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]')`, but it doesn't work for a specific id selector `$('#link')`. Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/coolakul/mfLjykb0/ .Like I said this needs to work only on a single element selected by the id.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the logic, please change `id="#link"` to `id="link"`. I have also updated the answer with `id`